# How can I handle the user access to specific taxonomy terms?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, users

There is a node form with a term reference field which's terms list I want to filter based on users/ permissions.

I've tried several modules in which I can grant access either user- or role-based for individual terms. Unfortunately, these settings are ignored by "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" when the views list is built.

So, whats the right way? How do I globally set per-term permissions that are also respected by views listings?

I've thought about changing the term controller but I don't see an access function there. Do I have to use a query alteration? Is there a hook?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try to add your own access checking in your view. A possible way to do so, is to use the [Views Access Callback](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_access_calback) module, which you can yuse in a custom module to make your view perform whatever access check you want. Some more details about this [Views Access Callback](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_access_calback) module (from its project page):

> Provides callback-based access control for Views.
>
> Available callback functions are defined by modules using `hook_views_access_callbacks()` function (in the same way as in `hook_perm()`), then could be set in in view's "Access restrictions" configuration.

The [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432528) for this module provides some extra details to get you going with this module.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will look into it. it will only provide access checks within views, right?

Comment: @Alex I think so ...

Comment: the module only provides a function to determine if the itself should be accessed, not single terms within the result set...

Comment: *if the view should be